# Configuring GCP ops agent to send logs for only one systemd service

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, stackdriver

I want to install the ops [agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/ops-agent) on a GCP VM and have it send logs from a systemd service to StackDriver.

However, the relevant docs do not [indicate](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/configuration#default) how to specify one (and only one) systemd service.

Is there a way to limit log reading (and dispatching to StackDriver) for only one systemd serrvice?

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting the receiver id for systemd service as mentioned in the link for other receivers like syslog(receiver id: transport_protocol) , tcp(receiver id: format) ?